# How to cd to a network drive on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

I want to execute a command via the `cmd` and the folder where I want to do that is a network-mapped drive `E:`.

[image]

Using the `cmd`, I would like to change to the directory, but getting an error:

```
C:\>e:
The system cannot find the drive specified.

C:\>cd e:
The system cannot find the drive specified.

C:\>cd /D e:
The system cannot find the drive specified.

C:\>
```

Searching on SO for similar problems, I came across a post that mentions using `pushd`:

```
C:\>pushd /D \\vboxsrv
The network name cannot be found.
```

Any tips?

Comment: Thanks. Is there easy way to move it there or do I have to delete/create?

Comment: `pushd "\\vboxsrv\share"` <--- assuming you have permissions.

Comment: foxidrive: getting `the syntax of the command is incorrect` error.

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
>pushd \\vboxsrv\Dropbox
```