# change to mapped network drive at command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, command-line

I have searched for the captioned question here and found these posts :

[How do I change to a mapped network drive at the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/221620/how-do-i-change-to-a-mapped-network-drive-at-the-command-line)

[Windows 7: Command Prompt won't CD into a network mapped drive](https://superuser.com/questions/303484/windows-7-command-prompt-wont-cd-into-a-network-mapped-drive)

but neither do they helped.

currently i have mapped a drive to F:, which i can access normally via explorer / GUI.

now i want to access it via command line, but when i do a simple :

```
F:
```

it says :

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

i also tried :

```
cd /d F:
```

it keeps saying :

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

alright. so then i tried the advice from one of the above posts

```
net use F:
```

it shows :

```
Local name     F:
Remote name    \\somewhere\shared
Resource type  Disk
The command completed successfully
```

so, what am i missing here? i tried all these on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that it's because i have started the command prompt as "admin", while all the network drives are mapped the account i normally using ( which has admin right as well though ), from there the OS has recognized me as a different person and so cannot see anything i mapped in the "normal" account.